# How to reinstall grub from a liveUSB if the / partition is encrypted and there is a separate /boot partition?

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, reinstall

I found few threads that explain how to reinstall grub2 by the mean of `chroot` but none of them explain how to proceed if my `/` is encrypted and if there is a plain `/boot` partition. Thing is I installed `Debian` in EFI mode and it made an unbootable entry (Japanese character) in the UEFI boot menu.

I tried to make a new entry using `efibootmgr` from Ubuntu liveUSB but it is still unbootable. I'd like to reinstall grub from Ubuntu liveUSB but I don't know to chroot the encrypted `/` partition and how the separate `/boot` partition blends in.

Comment: Given your configuration, you might want to try my [rEFInd boot manager,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) which tends to handle multi-distribution configurations better than GRUB. Try downloading the USB flash drive or CD-R version to see if it will boot both Debian and Ubuntu. (You may need to add extra boot options to identify your root filesystem by pressing F2 or Delete twice to boot Ubuntu.) If it works, you can install the PPA from Ubuntu or the Debian package in either Debian or Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

1. Boot from an Ubuntu Live USB with a working internet connection.
2. Open a Terminal window (*Applications* → *Accessories* → *Terminal*).
3. Type the following commands (pay attention to the comments, starting with `#`, after some commands):

   ```
   sudo -i
   apt-get update
   apt-get install cryptsetup lvm2
   fdisk -l
   cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda? TAG           # sda? is your root partition
   vgchange -ay
   vgscan
   vgchange -ay [VOLUME GROUP NAME]           # From the above command
   lvscan
   mount /dev/[VOLUME GROUP NAME]/[LOGICAL VOLUME NAME] /mnt          # LOGICAL VOLUME NAME from above command
   modprobe efivars
   mount /dev/sda? /mnt/boot/efi          # sda? is your efi partition
   mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev 
   mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
   mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
   mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
   cp /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/etc/
   chroot /mnt
   ```

   then do

   ```
   apt-get install --reinstall grub-efi-amd64
   ```

   or

   ```
   apt-get install --reinstall grub-efi
   ```

   and continue with

   ```
   update-grub
   umount /mnt
   vgchange -an
   cryptsetup luksClose TAG
   ```

Comment: One should also check out (https://askubuntu.com/a/831241/321153). I used a combined version of this and the one under link to fix my ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: `modprobe efivars` fails should it be `modprobe efivarfs` ?

Answer (score 0):

Took me a while getting lost doing this.  I have the same setup (non-encrypted /boot in ADDITION to a vfat /boot/efi).  The following debian guide nails it.  Missing pieces from all other guides were mounting the efivars and just comprehensive steps for grub re-installing etc.  Hope this helps!

https://wiki.debian.org/GrubEFIReinstall

Details on the specific parts that were missing from other answers here:

- include the efivars in the chroot whole installing grub

  for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /sys/firmware/efi/efivars /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done
- don't forget to mount /boot and then also /boot/efi in the chroot
- run *all the grub commands

  apt-get install --reinstall grub-efi

  grub-install /dev/disk

  update-grub

Thank you debian!!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1258649)