# How can I reinstall GRUB to the EFI partition?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I want to reinstall GRUB 2 and I found these instructions:
[How to Repair, Restore, or Reinstall Grub 2 with a Ubuntu Live CD or USB](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd).
In my case, the boot loader is installed in the EFI partition. If I use the commands provided in this guide, will GRUB be reinstalled to the EFI partition automatically, or will it be installed into the root partition where Ubuntu is installed ? Obviously, I do not want this to happen.

Comment: The instructions in the provided link are valid for reinstalling GRUB in legacy BIOS mode only, this will not work in your case. To reinstall GRUB to an Ubuntu installation in EFI BIOS mode, please read my answer. :)

Comment: Thank you very much! :) I have some questions:

when I installed Ubuntu in my UEFI system, I found two entries in the bios. Is there a way to have a unic ubuntu entry?
In case of MBR partition table (so no EFI or any other boot partition), can I use the same commands except for: sudo mount /dev/sd** /mnt/boot/efi ?

Comment: You can try to remove the second Ubuntu entry with : sudo efibootmgr (lists all entries) | sudo efi bootmgr -b <entry-number> -B .... and to reinstall GRUB in legacy BIOS mode execute these commands : sudo mount /dev/sd** /mnt | sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sd* (* = disk | ** = system partition) ! :)

Comment: Perfect :) Anyway, having a UEFI system and so a EFI partition, is there a way to avoid getting grub overriden when I perform a new Windows installation?

Comment: Well, Microsoft doesn't take care for anything else but their own products, so you can install Linux systems without doing any harm to Windows - unfortunately this isn't the case the other way around - so when you install Windows after you have installed Ubuntu, you have to restore the GRUB boot loader afterwards. :)

Comment: Clear :) Anyway, I tried to remove the second ubuntu entry (referred to grubx64.efi) with efibootmgr, but when I restart my computer it comes back! Instead, if I try to remove the other entry (that is referred to shimx64.efi), there are no problems. However, when I select ubuntu in the bios, it strangely loads successfully. I say strangely because I've read that, when secure boot is active, I must select the entry referred to shimx64.efi in order to load ubuntu properly! I'm a little bit confused..

Comment: What you read is true, when Secure Boot is enabled you boot with shimx64, when Secure Boot is disabled you boot with grubx64. This gives you both options, so my suggestion is to leave it just right the way it is. :)

Comment: Okk :) Then I'll rename the bios entries, so I can distinguish them and choose the proper one, depending on the Secure Boot state :)
Is there a command to restore the entry (shimx64) I deleted before? :D

Comment: Execute : sudo efibootmgr -c -w -d /dev/sd* -p 1 -L "ubuntu" -l '\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi' (* = disk) :)

Comment: In my opinion, the difference between the BIOS and EFI is difficult to live easily with. best to pick one

Comment: All current answers use chrooting but it did not work on my machine (I could not access my drives inside the chroot), so I added my answer that works without chrooting: https://askubuntu.com/a/1203713/541576

Answer (score 161, accepted):

Reinstall the GRUB boot loader to your Ubuntu installation in EFI mode this way ...

Boot from the Ubuntu installation medium and select 'Try Ubuntu without installing'.
(Boot your install medium in EFI mode, select the Ubuntu entry with UEFI in front.)

Once you are on the Live desktop, open a terminal and execute these commands :

```
sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt
sudo mount /dev/sdXX /mnt/boot/efi 

for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done  

sudo chroot /mnt  

grub-install /dev/sdX
update-grub
exit
```

Note: If the grub-install command reports an error, it cannot find efivars. Try the following while still in the chroot environment (Thanks to @michael_dunn - the step was necessary in Ubuntu 22.10) :

```
mount -t efivarfs none /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
```

Afterwards execute the `grub-install` command again : `grub-install /dev/sdX`

To avoid possible unexpected issues, properly unmount the file systems afterwards.

```
sudo umount /dev/sdXX
sudo umount /dev/sdXY
```

Note : `sdX` = disk | `sdXX` = efi partition | `sdXY` = system partition

To identify the partitions use GParted, the tool is included in the installation medium.
After having run the commands, GRUB will be installed in the separate EFI partition.

Comment: +1 but why don't you install from Ubuntu itself?

Comment: @MarkYisri : Thank you very much ! :) Because it is the safest way to reinstall the GRUB boot loader without corrupting things and in case the system does not boot properly ... the only way to do it ! :)

Comment: After exchanging an Intel NUC the new device didn't start from the old HDD. This fixed it. You made my day - thanks a lot!

Comment: In this solution, how does 'grub-install' know it is supposed to install in EFI mode?

Comment: @user334639 This happens right because the EFI partition gets recognized automatically ... :)

Comment: Thanks! And that's because the disk is formatted with GPT instead of MBR, is this right? Converting MBR to GPT would be a different question, is this right?

Comment: @user334639 Generally we can say that system installations on modern machines with an EFI based BIOS are deployed on disks with GPT partition table and system installations on older machines with MBR based BIOS are deployed on disks with "msdos" partition table. When the GRUB boot loader gets installed this will be detected automatically ... on system installations in legacy BIOS mode, an EFI partition does not exist. :)

Comment: The important point is to boot the installation media in the correct boot-mode, if we want to reinstall `grub-efi` we have to boot in UEFI-mode, if we wanty to reinstall `grub-pc` we have to boot in legacy-mode.

Comment: @mook765 Thanks for your contribution ! Although this should be an obviously known fact, I think that the information you provided is useful, especially for not so experienced users. Hence I decided to include it in the answer. :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for this post. When you say " `sdXXX ` = System partition" do you mean the partition assigned to `/`, `/home` or `/boot`? Thanks

Comment: Hi @ChrisRogers You're welcome ! :) `sdXXX` is the system partition, which means : `/` (the root partition).

Comment: Fantastic, cheers for that.

Comment: Installing Ubuntu 18.04, only `grub-pc` was available.  Had to first run `sudo apt-get install grub-efi`, then these steps.  Still got an error message on `grub-install`, but ignored it and ran `update-grub`, which found the Windows EFI.  I then had to reboot, enter the boot management, and update the Boot Sequence option.  It wasn't listed, but it gave me the option to add a boot option, then search for file, which I found in the right file system + EFI directory.  Set the new boot option as first, and it finally worked!

Comment: This worked for me except with one alteration: I did `grub-install /dev/sdXX`, i.e. not the disk but the EFI partition was used for installing grub and it worked.

Comment: I think if you do this
1) after purging Windows partitions,
2) whilst identifying partitions using UUIDs in /etc/fstab,
you need to update at least the /boot/efi UUID in your /etc/fstab (make sure other are correct as well). You can find partition IDs using `blkid`

Comment: What about 32-bit version?

Comment: This really helped me. I’ve been scouring the internet to find a solution.

Comment: Thanks for this solution it worked. I'd like to add that i had troubles after the procedure with startup time (~3min system boot / startup). I had to update /etc/fstab with the right UUID of the efi partition. Just compare the UUIDs of the efi partition of `sudo blkid` and the one of /etc/fstab...

Comment: Can someone explain me what the third command does `for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done` ?

Comment: @Vivek It binds `/dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run` from the live system to the mounted installed system, so that the commands you execute on the live system can effectively make the changes to the mounted installed system. It is a shorter version of these commands :
`sudo mount -o bind /dev /mnt/dev`
`sudo mount -o bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts`
`sudo mount -o bind /proc /mnt/proc`
`sudo mount -o bind /run /mnt/run`
`sudo mount -o bind /sys /mnt/sys`

Comment: In my case, the grub-install step failed with "read-only partition". So I went out of the chroot, unmounted the efi partition, then remounted it with --rw. Went back into the chroot and then the reinstall was successful. This was on a Ubuntu 20.04 live CD.

Comment: Works fine with Ubuntu 20.04 after: deleted all Windows partitions, moved Ubuntu partition and formated EFI partition. Thanks !

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. +1

Comment: you sir are a god and an upvote is not nearly enough repayment

Comment: @cl-netbox Hi follow all the step as you said but when I excute the grub-install /dev/sda it's taking to long... It's now over 5 hours what should I do? Stop it?.. Note: I deleted EFI partition accidentally in past.

Comment: Hi @RohitNishad :) An EFI partition is mandatory to let any operating system boot at all. The EFI partition should be the first partition on the disk and must be formatted with FAT (fat32). Recreate the partition with GParted by booting from the installation medium ... in case you are not sure how to perform everything, it probably might be more easy for you to completely reinstall the Ubuntu operating system from scratch.

Comment: I don't known why my PVE (debian based) can't boot (uefi fail, no grub screen) after a power failure. this really save my life.

Comment: I had "bad" settings that was causing grub to fail and this was just reinstalling grub with those same settings.  Before running `update-grub` I edited `/etc/defaults/grub` and removed the bad settings.  I'm not 100% sure how it was finding the non-default grub file -- when non-chrooted, it had normal defaults, but from within the chrooted terminal window, I saw my "bad" settings.

Comment: this method has helped even in case of "Locked ESP detected" error. as further boot fixes has been done with the BIOS assistance: AMI BIOS proposed to fix EFI database errors.

Comment: This worked for me with 2 modifications: After chroot:
mount -t efivarfs none /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
and grub-install /dev/sdXX

Comment: It's not right in front of me now, but I remember reading in some rescue CD's manual about this, or a very similar solution, and in there it was emphasized how important it is to correctly unmount the filesystems afterwards. Apparently, rebooting at this state without proper unmounting, carries a not unsignificant risk of damage to these crucial partitions, that may impose a new, harder to solve impediment on booting. Given the popularity of this answer, I would include here the codeblock for the unmounting part too.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @Levente ! Although it's a commonly known practice, I have added the part of unmounting the file systems nevertheless. Well, you are right ... better be safe than sorry. :)

Comment: For how long should I expect it to say "umount: /mnt: target is busy"? If it does this forever does that indicate some other problem? (in my specific case, Ubuntu isn't booting after multiple tries of a fresh install)

Comment: @KernelDeimos : As you say "Ubuntu isn't booting after multiple tries of a fresh install" ... yes, you most certainly are facing some other problems.

Comment: @cl-netbox turns out I had to rename ubuntu/boot/grubx64.efi to Microsoft/Boot/bootmfgw.efi or something like that... it was uncomfortable and strange

Comment: what's the reason to boot from installation medium when I can boot into final ubuntu already? Thx

Comment: @ying : You ask "What's the reason to boot from installation medium ?" Firstly, the main reason is that this is the safest way to reinstall the GRUB boot loader. Secondly, most users need to reinstall the boot loader only in case they can NOT boot into the installed system ... And, why else should someone want to reinstall the boot loader when everything works as expected ? :)

Answer (score 17):

this is the only way that worked for me:
(System: sdb8, boot: sdb6, efi: sdb2)

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb8 /mnt 
sudo mount /dev/sdb6 /mnt/boot 
sudo mount /dev/sdb2 /mnt/boot/efi

sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev &&
sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts &&
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc &&
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys

sudo chroot /mnt

grub-install --target=x86_64-efi /dev/sdb

grub-install --recheck /dev/sdb

exit &&
sudo umount /mnt/sys &&
sudo umount /mnt/proc &&
sudo umount /mnt/dev/pts &&
sudo umount /mnt/dev &&
sudo umount /mnt
```

Comment: What does `--recheck` do? The manual says `delete device map if it already exists`?

Comment: If I call the boot-entry anything different the the default, e.g. `--bootloader-id=Ubuntu_02` the boot fails. It just boot in the grub console...any solution?

Comment: yes. it seems `grub-install --recheck` is needed. It fixed my non-working USB HDD EFI.

Comment: Worth noting that for `--target=x86_64-efi` option to work you need a package `grub-efi-amd64-bin`

Comment: Would like to see a revision with some `for` loops

Answer (score 14):

This is how I did it on a standard x86_amd64 EFI desktop, without chrooting, assuming you have a partition containing Ubuntu on your hard drive and possibly an EFI partition where GRUB should be installed.

boot on a live Ubuntu, I used 18.04 but more recent should work

if you have currently no EFI partition (maybe it was deleted,
or you are migrating to a new drive):

```
sudo gparted
```

create a FAT 32 partition of around 100 MB on the disk of your choice
(in general the one that host the Ubuntu partition). If you plan to
move or resize some paritions, anticipate that (for instance by
creating the EFI partition at the end of the free space).

set the flag esp on this partition (the flag boot will also be selected)

if the directory /sys/firmware/efi/efivars is empty, run:

```
mount -t efivarfs none /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
```

after which is should not be empty anymore

now assuming that the Ubuntu partition is `/dev/sda2` and the (possibly new) EFI partition is `/dev/sda1`

```
sudo apt install grub-efi
sudo mkdir /media/root && sudo mount /dev/sda2 /media/root
sudo mkdir /media/efi && sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/efi
```

if you use Secure Boot, add the argument --uefi-secure-boot to grub-install command below

```
sudo grub-install --target=x86_64-efi /dev/sda --efi-directory=/media/efi --boot-directory=/media/root/boot
```

This should give:

> Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
>
> Installation finished. No error reported.

Then reboot and you should be done. You may have to tell your BIOS which drive to use, or which EFI partition to use, or which EFI binary to use.

If you created a new EFI partition, you may have to add it to `/etc/fstab` to have `update-grub` working correctly.

For more information : https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Multiboot_USB_drive#Hybrid_UEFI_GPT_+_BIOS_GPT/MBR_boot

[source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/693111/166985) for how to populate `/sys/firmware/efi/efivars` (else grub-install warns: `warning: EFI variables are not supported on this system`)

[source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/746260/166985) for how to make it work with Secure Boot.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I used modification of this. Since I was converting VM from BIOS to EFI I just formatted the existing `/boot` that was `ext` to `fat` using command `mkfs -t vfat /dev/sda2` (in MY case!) then mounted it with `mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/boot/` and also mounted my root (LVM). I've pointed both directory options to same place `grub-install --force --target=x86_64-efi --boot-directory=/mnt/boot --efi-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sda`. Then I've edited fstab that was mounted in `/mnt/root/etc/fstab` and replaced UUIDs with `/dev/sda2` + `vfat` and `/dev/mapper/..` for LVM.  <continues>

Comment: (sorry, comment limit) Anyway, after (successful!!!) reboot, I still repeated it inside the OS (VM) itself, by running `grub-install /dev/sda --efi-directory=/boot` + `update-grub` + another reboot. I tested this by installing another kernel, and forcing `update-grub`, and everything was fine, grub files were updated correctly, and new entries for this kernel were created. So thanks a lot once again, cheers!

Comment: My particular case with Ubuntu VM as answer on serverfault: https://serverfault.com/a/1047507/574185

Comment: Helped a lot. The disk in my system was still OK, but reaching it's capacity. So I transferred all the data to the new one (btrfs send/receive), created the new EFI partition, copied contents from the old EFI and followed your instructions. Then after rebooting with the new disk I found that the `grub.cfg` created by `grub-install` references the `grub.cfg` in `/boot/grub` (that lives on the btrfs partition). This one did still have the previous disk's UUIDs in the menu, so it wouldn't boot. Fixed the ID there (use `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid` to find the new ID), works like a charm now. Thanks!

Comment: I upvoted this but found that the `update-grub` step is missing from the instruction, which IMHO is the biggest flaw of this solution as `update-grub` is most often a critical step that most people cannot miss (and I guess that it has to be done within `chroot`).

Answer (score 10):

During the last months there have been some updates to the libraries involved.

The steps below were useful for me. They took ideas from old answers as well as from other forums.

**Make sure that you booted using EFI**

```
efibootmgr -v
```

**Run grub-install**

```
sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p5 /mnt 
sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 /mnt/boot/efi

for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /sys/firmware/efi/efivars /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done

sudo chroot /mnt

grub-install --target=x86_64-efi /dev/nvme0n1
grub-install --recheck /dev/nvme0n1

# as a second attempt, you could also try (assuming _debian_ is your distro)
# grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi --bootloader-id=debian
# grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg

update-grub2

exit &&
sudo umount /mnt/sys &&
sudo umount /mnt/proc &&
sudo umount /mnt/dev/pts &&
sudo umount /mnt/dev &&
sudo umount /mnt
```

**Make sure that `efibootmgr` lists your Linux as an entry**

```
efibootmgr -v
```

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to @cl-netbox for the instructions!

After I upgraded (Linux Mint 18.2 Sonya to 18.3 Sylvia) my system wouldn't boot so I followed the instructions above but still no success. I noticed however that my machine has /boot in a separate partition (possibly because I am using LVM) so my slightly modified process was:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdXXX /mnt
sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt/boot
sudo mount /dev/sdXX /mnt/boot/efi
for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done
sudo chroot /mnt
grub-install /dev/sdX
update-grub
```

Note : sdX = disk | sdXX = efi partition | sdXY = boot partition | sdXXX = system partition

Comment: I had a running Ubuntu Bionic system on which I accidentally did rm -Rf /boot/efi ! My system was still running, so I tried using the last two commands (grub-install /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root AND update-grub). Rebooted, and everything work perfectly. Phewy and thanks :)

Comment: With LVM, the beginning should look like this: sudo vgchange -ay name_of_:the_lvg and then sudo mount /dev/sname_of_:the_lvg/root /mnt

Answer (score 6):

Also, if booting from Live CD to recover, it might happen that you are missing the `grub-efi-amd64-bin` package and then the line:

```
grub-install --target=x86_64-efi /dev/sdb
```

fails with error message:

```
grub-install: error: /usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi/modinfo.sh doesn't exist. Please specify --target or --directory.
```

In this case, run this outside of `chroot`:

```
sudo apt get grub-efi-amd64-bin
```

and then add `/usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi` to `chroot` mounts.

BTW, the `/dev/sdb` parameter is obsolete and is being ignored.

Comment: I wonder what `sudo apt get grub-efi-amd64-bin` will do.

Comment: `sudo apt get grub-efi-amd64-bin` is not a valid command. Perhaps you mean `sudo apt install ...`

Answer (score 4):

If you happen to lose your EFI partition, it's easy to get it back. You can use a partitioning tool such as `fdisk` or `parted` to create a new partition sdXY (e.g. sda1) with type "EFI partition (1)" and format it with:

```
sudo mkfs.msdos /dev/sdXY
```

then mount it with:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdXY /boot/efi
```

and you can reinstall GRUB by running:

```
sudo grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi
```

as mentioned in other solutions.

Comment: Surely you format a partition on the disk i.e. /dev/sdX1, and not the whole block device?

Answer (score 4):

I can't comment (not enough reputation), but  @Chilu Pereira's answer is the way to go in an EFi or multiboot situation. It is similar to the approach in the gentoo-guide.
They use a slightly different approach :
Instead of a `mount --bind` they use `mount --rbind` followed by `mount --make-rslave` for sys and dev and proc gets simply mounted again.
In gentoo I used to create mounts from a live-system like this:

```
mount -t proc /proc /mnt/proc
mount --rbind /sys /mnt/sys
mount --make-rslave /mnt/sys
mount --rbind /dev /mnt/dev
mount --make-rslave /mnt/dev 
chmod 1777 /mnt/dev/shm
```

(Anybody knows what is exactly the difference between `--bind` and `--rbind / --make-rslave` btw ?)

But today I got two errors in chroot from grub2, I never experienced before :

```
 connect: No such file or directory
   Please make sure that the zfs-fuse daemon is running
```

and

```
grub-install: warning: Cannot read EFI Boot* variables.
grub-install: warning: read_file: could not read from file: Input/output error.
```

The zfs-fuse error seems not to matter but for Efivars I had to add one more mount :

```
mount --bind /sys/firmware/efi/efivars /mnt/sys/firmware/efi/efivars
```

I guess /sys/firmware/efi/efivars does not exist in chroot or maybe it's read only -
but anyway it worked

Comment: Agreed, that answer was the one that fixed up my grub install without borking the existing Apple partition (I don't think bind-mounting `/dev/pts` is needed though)

Comment: the `/dev/pts`  thing can be found in many tutorials and manuals . As `/dev/pts` are pseudo-terminals and a bind mount, it may not be needed.

Comment: I just found the explanation why you should prefer `--rbind`  over `--bind`  as `--rbind` gives access to other bind-mounts underneath the bind-mount you are creating. A better explanation is here : [https://askubuntu.com/a/1188621/260981]

Comment: I'm guessing the *r* is for recursive. I've not heard of that option. I'm not sure offhand if there are any other mount points under '/sys', but if there are then i hope 'rbind' has loop detection!

Answer (score 3):

in addition to ci-netbox answer.
If your pendrive OS version does not match the one that is installed on the disk,  grub-install may have difficulties to identify the right grub installation:

```
$ sudo chroot /mnt
# grub-install /dev/sdX
grub-install: error: /usr/lib/grub/i386-pc/modinfo.sh doesn't exist. 
Please specify --target or --directory.
```

Try to identify manually the installation to use

```
# ls /usr/lib/grub/
grub-mkconfig_lib  x86_64-efi  x86_64-efi-signed
```

Then restart grub-install :

```
# grub-install --target=x86_64-efi /dev/sdX 
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
```

Answer (score 2):

Took me a while getting lost doing this. I have the same setup (non-encrypted /boot in ADDITION to a vfat /boot/efi). The following debian guide nails it. Missing pieces from all other guides were mounting the efivars and just comprehensive steps for grub re-installing etc. Hope this helps!

https://wiki.debian.org/GrubEFIReinstall

Details on the specific parts that were missing from other answers here:

- include the efivars in the chroot whole installing grub

  ```
  for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /sys/firmware/efi/efivars /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done
  ```
- don't forget to mount `/boot` and then also `/boot/efi` in the chroot
- run *all* the grub commands

  ```
  apt-get install --reinstall grub-efi
  grub-install /dev/disk
  update-grub
  ```

Thank you debian!!

Answer (score 0):

Just used this tool https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair on Ubuntu. That was the easiest way and all was automatic.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest for me was to use this small tool (20 Mb) that will let you boot the broken grub system (I used Ventoy to boot the tool):

https://www.supergrubdisk.org/category/download/supergrub2diskdownload/

And once the tool has made its magic and booted your linux systen, do:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/nvme0n1
sudo update-grub
```

Answer (score 0):

I used Grub-Customizer. I know some of you don't like this program, but in some cases it comes in very handy ( renaming Ubuntu in Kubuntu ( don't have to do that in 'etc/grub.d/10_Linux_Proxy' ), add a theme, or in this case.

File --> Install in MBR.

And all was done.

I don't use Linux based OS's that long ( 7 or 8 months now ), and if I have to write everything down to use in the command-line, it not only takes a long time ( mostly the writing down ), but I can make errors that way.

I had my Windows Bootloader in partition 1 and grub2 in another EFI partition ( 8 )( didn't want to mess up Windows Bootloader ), so every time I wanted to use my Kubuntu ( daily ) or Mint OS I had to press F11, wait, select USB ( don't ask me why ), select Ubuntu, then wait again for Grub and then select my Linux based OS. Now I get Grub2 almost instantly.

Update 211111/1135
Like Organic Marble commented 'MBR doesn't sound right for a UEFI system', he is right. It worked, but only once. What I did is install Grub2Win in my Win10 installation. From Kubuntu I could export my 'grub.conf´ to the 'My Documents'-partition ( NTFS, so Win10 can read that ) and imported it in Grub2Win. Now it is working like it is suposed to.

PS.
I saved this page, so I know how to do it when I get rid of Windows.

Comment: Installing to MBR doesn't sound right for a UEFI system.

Comment: @ Organic Marble. No, you are right. Doesn't sound good. It worked though. Only 1 time. So clearly this is not the right way.