# ubuntu has been blocked by the current security policy in ubuntu 17.10

Tags: boot, uefi

I'm using a Ubuntu 17.10 only machine. I recently had a notification mentioning certain packages were missing and i had to a partial upgrade. So after the upgrade when I rebooted the laptop, I'm getting "ubuntu has been blocked by the current security policy".

The current boot mode is 'legacy support' and 'legacy first' and I'm still getting the same error.

When I switch it to UEFI I'm receiving a "Default Boot Device Missing or Boot Failed " error.

I'm not able to power ON my laptop.
Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ubuntu has been blocked by the current security policy

This probably means you boot in legacy mode and the system can not find a legacy installation. Generally I would use [boot repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) to fix this. Besides a download+burn ISO you can also do this from a live session with an internet connections:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

> Default Boot Device Missing or Boot Failed

Same but for EFI. To reinstall EFI from a live session see [Reinstalling Grub2 (EFI partition)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/831216/reinstalling-grub2-efi-partition) and cl-netbox's answer.

Comment: Your first solution to use boot-repair worked, I did have to try it a couple times. But it worked. Thanks a lot!!!