# Manually install GRUB on EFI partition

Tags: 16.04, grub2, grub-efi

I know that there are plenty of topics already and I've tried to follow them, but I'm still stuck and can't install the GRUB. I've tried to follow the steps from the accepted answer [in this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/831216/reinstalling-grub2-efi-partition).

I have the following partitions:

- `/dev/mmcblk1p1` - EFI Syste Partition fat32 512mb
- `/dev/mmcblk1p2` - ext4 26.68GB
- `/dev/mmcblk1p3` - linux-swap 1.94GB

I executed these commands:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/mmcblk1p2 /mnt
$ sudo mount /dev/mmcblk1p1 /mnt/boot/efi
$ for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done
$ sudo chroot /mnt
$ grub-install /dev/mmcblk1
$ update-grub
```

But I am getting the following errors:

```
grub-install: warning: this GPT partition label contains no BIOS Boot
Partition; embedding won't be possible. grub-install: warning:
Embedding is not possible. GRUB can only be installed in this setup by
using blocklists. However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is
discouraged.. grub-install: error: will not proceed with blocklists.
```

These are the boot options from BIOS:
[image]

Comment: ubuntu is in legacy mode. you need grub-efi installed

Comment: @ravery can you please a bit more specific? I did install grub-efi package but what to do next?

Comment: You booted your live-session in legacy-mode. Boot your live-session in UEFI-mode and retry.

Comment: @mook765 is it done in BIOS? I have no such option when I just boot from my USB drive. I have "try ubuntu without installing", "install ubuntu", "oem install", "check disc for defects"

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev Yes, you have to make the right choice in your bios-boot-menu. Check your bios-options if UEFI-boot-mode is enabled.

Comment: @mook765 I've updated the question. What do I need to do there?

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev Looks like you have to choose `UEFI: KingstonDataTraveller` to boot in UEFI-mode from your USB-stick.

Comment: @mook765 it is the USB drive where I have ubuntu ISO image. I choosed it and installed ubuntu and then stuck with grub as described in the question

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev Strange, your output indicates legacy-mode. You could stick with legacy-mode, but you would have to create a small (1MB) `BIOS-boot`-partition if you keep GPT-partition-table or you change to MBR-partitioning and reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

I assume, you have a legacy BIOS disk image. and you try to replicate to other computer with UEFI.
from all the steps you've done. watch this part!
`sudo mount /dev/mmcblk1p1 /mnt/boot/efi`
before doing that, of course you have to `sudo mkdir /mnt/boot/efi`

`sudo chroot /mnt`
after this, of course you have to `sudo apt install -y grub-efi` or `sudo apt install -y grub-efi-amd64-signed`

`grub-install /dev/mmcblk1`
don't forget to add `--target=x86_64-efi` or `--target=i386-pc` and `--force` and `--removable` (this is because you want it on removable device, right?).

It may look like this:
`grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --force --removable /dev/mmcblk1`
or
`grub-install --target=i386-pc --force --removable /dev/mmcblk1`