# Problem in Installing Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: system-installation, 18.04, dell

I've been struggling to install Ubuntu 18.04 on brand new Dell G5 15 - Gaming Laptop.

I followed all the instructions in the existing answers about this matter, but no luck yet!

### Sample of What I've Tried

I went to the Bios and did the followings:

- Disabled Secure Boot
- Changed SATA from RAID to AHCI
- Bios is already in UEFI Boot Mode
- Also tried to disable PTT and Enable Legacy Mode

For the Installation:

- I pressed `e` and added `acpi=off` so the installation splash screen is not freezing anymore.
- I partitioned the HD to mount `/boot/efi`, swap area, root `/`.
- I always connect to Internet before the installation.
- [These answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028921/the-grub-efi-amd64-signed-package-failed-to-install-into-target-during-ins)

### The Error

It keeps installing all packages until it reaches the grub-efi-amd64-signed, then it throws:

```
grub-efi-amd64-signed package failed to install into target
```

---

Following are some screenshots:

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0btcq.jpg)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbYJa.jpg)

[Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDhAd.jpg)

---

Any Help is a Trillion Time Appreciated!

Comment: did you create the partition map yourself or let the install do it? you selected the "erase everything and install" option?

Comment: @JoshuaBesneatte Yes I created it myself.

Comment: I would say to let the install handle the partitioning, and see if that works. Don't do any customization, just erase and install and it should work just fine.

Comment: keep in mind this will set up for your system... so if you have bios in efi mode, it will set up for that (efi partition, etc), and if in legacy mode it will set up for that ( no efi partition )

Comment: @JoshuaBesneatte I'll try and report back. Thanks.

Comment: @JoshuaBesneatte I tried and it did not work either.. maybe because there are two built-in driver one is NVME and the second is SATA?

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue on the same model, and I also tried everything listed above. I can finish the install but the computer won't shut down or boot after. When installing Ubuntu I don't get the error message, but I also tried installing Mint and the error message appeared during their install and produced the same problems -- so I'm working under the assumption that the grub-efi-amd64-signed is missing. I also tried - custom partitions, default partitions, encrypted (I'd prefer encrypted) - not downloading updates, not installing 3rd party drivers
- installing without an internet co