# Efi issue Ubuntu 18 after deleting windows and efi partition

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

Output of http://bootinfoscript.sourceforge.net/ Boot Info Script version: 0.61
Release date:             1 April 2012

is at https://pastebin.com/cGWTnEiR

Short version deleted /efi partition. Only want Ubuntu. getting errors on boot but able to boot. Have old NTFS partition that i dont want to format. Anyway to fix? have USB with ubuntu 18 if need be.

https://photos.app.goo.gl/cZdujjV7mVHMzHn56 images of boot error. Can I fix without formatting and reinstalling?

*Long version:*

Got laptop 3 years back, Installed Ubuntu 16 along side win 10. Messed around a month back, got ubuntu 18 on a new partition.

Wanted to make some space deleted some files.

Moved out home folder to a new partition.

Needed space for some videos on traffic safety ... decided to get rid of Windows as hardly use it now. Alls well. Then went to Gparted to sort free space, Got windows c drive clubbed into UbuHome partition, thumbs up!

Then deleted efi partition. oops 1.
Then for some silly 2am reason "noticed" untried menu in Gparted, created a new partition. Not a nice interface by the way -> did not need to apply like other actions just a warning and done :( oops 2

Tried to use testdisk, it got back my NTFS d drive and ubu home ...but also got a bunch of many other drives. But UbuHome was not loading after i tried ot merge some of hte other false partitions with it.

Anyway now have deleted UbuHome, got a fresh Ubuntu 18, with old NTFS d working as a seperate partiion

But efi not recreaed fully.

Tried installing grub again -> no errors but no cigar. Followed https://askubuntu.com/a/831241/165511 (not exact answer found similar one when i booted via Usb)

Also tried:

```
sudo parted -l
[sudo] password for t: 
Model: ATA KINGSTON SV300S3 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 480GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size    Type      File system  Flags
 1      1048kB  125GB  125GB   extended
 5      1049kB  200MB  199MB   logical   fat32        boot, esp
 6      201MB   450MB  249MB   logical
 7      451MB   125GB  124GB   logical   ext4
 3      125GB   403GB  278GB   primary   ntfs
 4      403GB   480GB  77.6GB  primary   ext4


t@t-Aspire-E5-573G:~$ sudo grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=esp --bootloader-id=GRUB
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: error: failed to get canonical path of `esp'.
t@t-Aspire-E5-573G:~$ sudo grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=epi --bootloader-id=GRUB
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: error: failed to get canonical path of `epi'.
t@t-Aspire-E5-573G:~$ sudo grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi --bootloader=ubuntu --boot-directory=/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu --recheck
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Primary GPT is invalid, using alternate GPT.
Primary GPT is invalid, using alternate GPT.
Primary GPT is invalid, using alternate GPT.
Installation finished. No error reported.
```

https://photos.app.goo.gl/cZdujjV7mVHMzHn56 images of boot error then when i choose first option it works - goes to log on screen. just want to get rid of the error so it goes to hard disk. Fyi the ubuntu16 and u Oses are all removed now. Just a single boot ubuntu 18 laptop now.

Comment: You don't need to add "solved" to the question on Ask Ubuntu. You can ["accept" an answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) here instead.

Comment: does not let me for 2 days so did not want folks to read the question only to later see that its solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Looked at other forums and psots on askubuntu.com USed boot-repair but still same.

Then went to system menu (pressed F2 key before boot error appeared), under security.

Deleted all current boot info.

Saved and exited.

Again went there and choose ubuntu efi

On rebooth said no booth device.

Did boot repair again.

Rebooth. Same  no booth device.

Rebooth to boot menu, choose Ubuntu again under security - trusted boots

Now its working.