# Ubuntu 19.04 grub error: relocation 0x0 is not implemented yet

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I boot my laptop today as usual and this error appeared:

```
relocation 0x0 is not implemented yet
Aborted. press any key to exit
```

Then it went into windows boot manager after pressing any key. I'm using Ubuntu 19.04 on Asus FX504GD, dual boot with Windows 10. I googled and found that this is a Grub error and seems to be related to rescue mode, but I found no solution. I couldn't think of any thing that I have done recently to cause this error. A detailed instruction (e.g. making required cammands explicit) will be greatly appreciated for a newbie like me. Thank you.

Comment: Can you reach GRUB menu by pressing `shift` key while restart? If so, do you observe Windows 10 and Ubuntu boot loaders there? Please reply. Thanks.

Comment: @Marmayogi pressed `shift` while restart and entered windows advanced boot menu. After pressing `Use a device`, there are both windows boot manager and Ubuntu, but that seems to be equivalent to pressing `ESC` while booting, which result in the same error while selecting `Ubuntu`.

Comment: Restart your system and press `shift` or `esc` key to enter into GRUB menu. Use `Up/Dn` arrows to select `Ubuntu` and then press `e`. A screen will appear, and look for the line `linux`. Use `Up/Dn` arrows and reach that line. Press `end` key to reach end of line containing `linux`. Now type a `space` character followed by **3**. Press  `Ctrl+X` to boot. You will be taken to terminal `TTY` and there you enter your login `username` and `password`.

Comment: (continue from previous comment....) Please run commands `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get upgrade` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`. Now you issue command `sudo update-grub`. Finally type `reboot`. After rebooting reach GRUB menu by pressing `shift` or `esc` key and try to boot by selecting `ubuntu`. Please report. Thanks.

Comment: @Marmayogi Thank you for your help. But I cannot enter GRUB menu. When I select Ubuntu in the boot menu (by pressing `ESC` when booting) it shows the error mentioned in the main post. The same thing happens if I don't press anything as it boot into GRUB by default. Therefore, I don't know how to issue the command you have mentioned.

Comment: Please explain the phrase **When I select Ubuntu in the boot menu**. `Selecting` means did you type a <return> key after focusing `Ubuntu` bootloader using Up/Dn keys?

Comment: If I pressed `esc` while powering on the device, a list with a few options appears, including windows boot manager and ubuntu (and a few other systems which are removed and no longer exist on this device). I can navigate by pressing up/down. But choosing ubuntu results in the error mentioned above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93574/discussion-between-marmayogi-and-frank-wang).

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question (even though this is a bit stupid) since I just found a solution myself and I want to share it to help others.

I entered live system with a live usb and tried grub repair tool following [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) instruction. Then, I can boot into my system correctly even though a few new options appear in my grub menu. Still not sure what caused the problem. Please tell me if you have any idea.

Thanks to @Marmayogi for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

I received this error on boot also. It was after I tried to shut dual booting ubuntu 20.04.03 LTS. It asked me to authorise the shutdown as there was still another users apps running (or something). Anyway - it messed up the boot and I got the relocation error.

I tried the sequence above but the repair tool would not apply recommended fixes because it detected that the tool was booted in BIOS mode but the boot sequence was UEFI, and I should be booted in the same mode to make the changes. my BIOS is 2012 and for some reason wouldn't boot the USB in UEFI.

my 20.04 install had created an EFI partition, and so I had to find a way to reinstall grub in the EFI partition.

I found the answer in this post re [installing grub in the EFI partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/831216/how-can-i-reinstall-grub-to-the-efi-partition):

```
grub-install --target=x86_64-efi /dev/sdb
```

I think this must force grub to install into the Efi mounted partition. on reboot it had forgotten about windows, and booted direct to ubuntu.  I used the steps from this post on [adding windows 10 to the grub menu](https://superuser.com/questions/1392316/how-to-add-windows-10-to-grub-boot-loader), and it is all back to normal.