# Not able to boot into Ubuntu after deleting Windows

Tags: boot, 18.04, grub2

So I had a dual boot system where I had Windows and Ubuntu. Since windows wasn't needed I had deleted it. Now I'm not able to boot into anything as it says there is nothing to boot into.

I then used a live usb of  Ubuntu 18.04. Using that I can access my Ubuntu as I see all my files and folders.

Running `fdisk -l` shows that I have Ubuntu installed on `/dev/sda8` and there is grub installed on `/dev/sda1`.

Now it looks like this:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 238.5 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 0F9F7ABB-A37C-4FE7-8496-93B1538A2283

Device Start End Sectors Size Type
/dev/sda8 2048 500105215 500103168 238.5G Linux filesystem
```

`/dev/sda8` disk contains 120+ Gb of data.

How can I enable grub at startup so I can boot into Ubuntu? I am a newbie in installing multi-OS so please let me know if any additional info is needed.

Comment: why grub was installed on a partition, not on disk. You can use `boot-repair` utility from a liveusb to fix it.

Comment: Try this: https://askubuntu.com/a/326661/925971

Comment: @Gryu When I try to boot-repair I get "The boot of your PC is in EFI mode, but no EFI partition was detected. You may want to retry after creating a EFI partition(FAT32, 100MB~250MB, start of the disk,boot flag).
"

Comment: Then look at this: https://askubuntu.com/a/831241/925971

Comment: @Gryu Can you help me what is the `X`, `XX`, `XXX` mentioned in the answer?Thanks

Comment: `sdX` is `sda`, `sdXX` is `sda1`

Comment: @Gryu Thanks. What about sdXXX?

Comment: I think, that is `sda8` with your ubuntu system. But you could show us `ls /dev/sd*` command output.

Comment: @Gryu Thanks! Will try it out

Comment: But there should be present efi partition and boot partition. Maybe you need to repartition your sda1 into three partitions with mount points `/boot`, `/boot/efi`, `/home`. `/boot` and `/boot/efi` should be small

Comment: @Gryu How would I do that? Sorry to trouble you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104641/discussion-between-gryu-and-krishnanspace).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way:

1. Backup your data
2. Reinstall Ubuntu by creating proper partition sizes for EFI, boot, root and home partitions: 100Mb, 1Gb, 60Gb, 175+Gb
3. Move your data back into /home partition

Without reinstalling:

1. Using GParted shrink `/dev/sda8` partition to get 1.2Gb of unallocated space. `/dev/sda8` partition should be unmounted.
2. Create a new partition for `/boot/efi` mount point of 100Mb size.
3. Create a new partition for `/boot` mount point of residual Unallocated space - 1+Gb size.
4. [Try](https://askubuntu.com/a/831241/925971) the next:

   `sudo mount /dev/sda8 /mnt`
   `sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt/boot` (see what it actually is in GParted or `fdisk -l` - it should be of 1+Gb size)
   `sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/boot/efi` (see what it is in GParted - it should be 100Mb size)
   `for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done`
   `sudo chroot /mnt`
   `grub-install /dev/sda`
   `update-grub`