# CAN'T INSTALL LINUX DISTRO(grub fail)

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, uefi, bootloader, grub-efi

boot-info: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/RfkJWSpQ4Z/

Sorry for asking this question again because it has been asked and answered multiple times but I could not find a solution that fits my problem.

I have bought a lenovo legion y530 (nvidia geforce gtx 1050ti and intel core i7 8th gen) almost a year ago and I have been trying to  install a linux distribution since the day I bought it :)

First, I cant install it on legacy mode because every time I try, it only gives a black screen.

For UEFI mode, it works perfectly and I always get at the end of the installation but every time it gives a grub2 error where it says it cant install it on /target.

I know it is installed, I see ubuntu on bios but when I boot it, I see grub terminal(and boot command gives something like "you need to load kernel!").

Could someone please help me install a linux distro please. I tried ubuntu, kali, debian, those are which I remember.

Tails works fine until the welcome screen where I click on start and it freezes.

I can not understand why I am the only one in my class who can't install linux and it has been very difficult for me because I am a software engineering student.

Thank you very much(for even reading this much :))

Comment: With that nvidia graphics card/chip I think you need the [boot option](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808) `nomodeset`. Have you tried that way?

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed most recently (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please do not use Add Comment.

Comment: You show grub installed in both BIOS and UEFI boot modes. Your fstab shows mount of ESP, so currently UEFI boot. Do not try to boot in BIOS/Legacy/CSM mode or you just will get grub error. But Windows is hibernated, from report: "Windows is hibernated, refused to mount." http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to install grub2 manually:

- Boot from your ubuntu installation usb flashdrive with **Try without installing** option
- Open terminal and do the next:

  ```
  sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt
  sudo mount /dev/sda3 /mnt/boot/efi
  for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done
  sudo chroot /mnt
  grub-install /dev/sda
  update-grub
  ```

[Reference](https://askubuntu.com/a/831241/925971)

But I recommend you to **backup all important data** before this. It should not destroy your data. But to avoid stress better do backups of important data every time you're working with partitions.