# installer put boot to hdd but system to ssd. How to fix

Tags: boot, grub2

I have a system with a HDD and a SSD. I was not wholly attentive when installing. I've done it many times on other systems and never had a problem so I was a bit trigger happy...

But with this system, somehow the HDD ended up being the boot drive while the SSD is the system drive. I don't understand at all, but that's what it looks like.

So I want to, I'm guessing here:

-- make the SSD bootable
-- install GRUB to the SSD

Here's the fdisk listing:

```
   Disk /dev/sda: 931.53 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
    Disk model: WDC WD10EAVS-98D
    Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    Disklabel type: dos
    Disk identifier: 0x304fe66b

    Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
    /dev/sda1  *     2048 1953523711 1953521664 931.5G 83 Linux




    Disk /dev/sdb: 223.58 GiB, 240057409536 bytes, 468862128 sectors
    Disk model: KINGSTON SA400S3
    Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    Disklabel type: dos
    Disk identifier: 0x1f87c004
    Device     Boot   Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
   /dev/sdb1          2048   1050623   1048576   512M  b W95 FAT32
   /dev/sdb2       1052670 468860927 467808258 223.1G  5 Extended
   /dev/sdb5       1052672 468860927 467808256 223.1G 83 Linux
```

Comment: This answer may help: https://askubuntu.com/a/831241/1048265. Identify the drive name of your SSD using `sudo blkid`, and modify the instructions to suit your drive name.

Comment: @Kurankat It had some useful information and stitched together a solution.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this using info from Kurankat's link.

**I fixed the grub** by putting the grub to /dev/sdb

```
 sudo grub-install /dev/sdb
 sudo update grub
```

I did this with the system running off its main disk i.e. /dev/sdb. I did not need to use a livecd.

==

**I fixed the boot** problem with gparted.

Using the 'Manage Flags' menu option I unchecked `boot` on `/dev/sda` and checked `boot` on `/dev/sdb1`.

I've rebooted a couple of times dealing with other issues and it is working very well.

Comment: Good to hear! I've had similar issues in the past, particularly when installing to an external hard drive, and the installer automatically adds the boot entries to the boot loader in the main drive.