# best practices for dual-booting with Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, uefi, windows-10, license

While [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot) makes sense:

> Instead, it is best to do a native install of Ubuntu, and then
>   virtualize the other operating system.

Windows licensing doesn't always make that a [reasonable](https://superuser.com/q/1545728/55747) option.  Which [leaves](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot):

> To accomplish this, the only thing in your computer outside of Ubuntu
>   that needs to be changed is a small code in the MBR (Master Boot
>   Record) of the first hard disk, or the EFI partition.

Are there any additional pointers to avoid boot problems?  The most recent question tagged `uefi` and `dual-boot` has, for example, a boot problem.

I'd only have a single hard drive and using `uefi` of course, with Window pre-installed.

For example, what if I need to re-install Windows?  Would that wipe out Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstalling Windows will override GRUB (bootloader) and you will have to reinstall GRUB. Your ubuntu files should stay intact given that you leave ubuntu partition(s) untouched.
So it makes sense to install Windows first then Ubuntu and let GRUB handle it from there

Comment: what about something like:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/REFInd ?

Comment: Actually I've not used it before. However this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/831216/how-can-i-reinstall-grub-to-the-efi-partition) can be helpful when trying to reinstall GRUB on EFI partition