# Cannot Load Ubuntu 20.04 alongside Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I have a Lenovo Helix 2nd gen tablet with Windows 10.

The problem is that when I boot it goes straight to Windows 10.

I have done the following:

1. Disabled Fast startup & secure boost
2. Loaded Ubuntu from USB and downloaded Boot_Repair but I get `GPT detected. Please create a BIOS-Boot partition (1>MB, unformatted file system, bios_grub flag)`.

Here is the bootInfo Summury-->https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/DKcDkmBRKJ/

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You could check if your efi boot partition is correctly installed. I had a similar problem some time ago.
Check out this answer it might help:
https://askubuntu.com/a/831241/634093