# How to reinstall Grub in the system EFI partition WITHOUT replacing the Windows bootloader

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

I would like to install Grub (which is missing) to the EFI partition, but I don't want to replace the Windows bootloader. This means that my computer will boot on Windows everytime, but the Grub bootmanager is installed in the EFI partition

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I reinstall GRUB to the EFI partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/831216/how-can-i-reinstall-grub-to-the-efi-partition)

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen i saw this post, but I am not sure? My computer will boot on Windows automatically and Grub will not show up? I just want to download it in the EFI partition

Comment: Grub always installs into a different folder in the ESP - efi system partition. When installed it will make ubuntu as first entry, but you can go into UEFI settings & change boot order to have Windows first. You then choose in UEFI boot when you want Ubuntu. Only if you erase ESP, before install which you normally would not do, would you lose your Windows boot.