# initramfs unpacking failed decoding failed: error after re-install Grub

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, mount

I have dual boot windows/ubuntu.
After trying to install new M.2 drive, I must have hit the CMOS or something and my RAID config got reset in my BIOS. So I enabled RAID again but my Ubuntu boot option disappeard. After some googling, I tried to re-install GRUB via Boot USB.  I followed the instructions in this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/831216/how-can-i-reinstall-grub-to-the-efi-partition)

Upon restarting, I get a grub boot menu, I select Ubuntu and then error: "initramfs unpacking failed decoding failed".

More googling tells me I need to switch `COMPRESS=lz4` to `COMPRESS=gzip` in the etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf. So I did this by loading Boot USB, mounting my / to /mnt and then chroot into it and editing the intramfs.conf.
After I edited it, I tried to run `update-initramfs -u` and I got error :
`W: Couldn't identify type of root file system for fsck hook`

My `/etc/fstab` :

```
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/isw_baffbgegbh_Volume1p8 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/dev/mapper/isw_baffbgegbh_Volume1p7 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2

swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0

UUID=9932-D05E  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults      0       1
```

and result of `sudo blkid`

```
/dev/mapper/isw_baffbgegbh_Volume1p4: UUID="362E787B2E7835C9" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="874795c7-2c6a-46ff-8faf-e8ad85989fb6"
/dev/mapper/isw_baffbgegbh_Volume1p1: UUID="9932-D05E" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="bbc8664e-ba5d-4339-b008-52c7d888450e"
/dev/mapper/isw_baffbgegbh_Volume1p2: UUID="353eb09f-1019-4fe0-873b-9ac455b08552" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="b4119b1b-7e2c-48b9-88e3-41e2e2bb9dcd"
/dev/mapper/isw_baffbgegbh_Volume1p3: UUID="B4AA01F3AA01B2C2" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="36c545d4-6661-471e-af41-c38a89b5e60d"
/dev/mapper/isw_baffbgegbh_Volume1p5: UUID="529AC9C19AC9A1B9" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="97ddcbf6-2bfb-41da-84a9-34ea28d29dc9"
/dev/mapper/isw_baffbgegbh_Volume1p7: UUID="2d6df6f0-9df0-49e1-b847-122f9bfeeb5b" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="4fcdf3d2-6b29-4a2c-8063-0c2483cbb442"
/dev/mapper/isw_baffbgegbh_Volume1p8: UUID="bf7d70a7-c14c-4b5c-9b8e-176c2d3ce7c2" TYPE="ext4" PTTYPE="dos" PARTUUID="86bcd4af-de29-4dfd-9a23-b284ce2ea905"
/dev/sdb: TYPE="isw_raid_member"
/dev/sda: TYPE="isw_raid_member"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop7: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sdc2: SEC_TYPE="msdos" UUID="0D5F-1DB6" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="663eb4c4-02"
/dev/mapper/isw_baffbgegbh_Volume1: PTUUID="a58fcf30-f4d6-4d13-bb2b-28cf1a480e23" PTTYPE="gpt"
/dev/sdc1: UUID="2018-07-25-03-21-56-00" LABEL="Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS amd64" TYPE="iso9660" PTUUID="663eb4c4" PTTYPE="dos" PARTUUID="663eb4c4-01"
```

So even if I restart and try to boot after changing the initramfs.conf, it still fails with same error. Anyone got a clue about this ? Im dumbfounded. Idk if it was some windows update that messed everything up or maybe a linux update I forgot about but this is super annoying.
I can boot into Windows just fine.

Comment: The same thing happened to me today, after upgrading grub2.