# Installing new windows version over dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04, windows, windows-10

I dual boot windows 10 and ubuntu 18.04 but I will install windows 10 pro, will something happen to the dual boot? and if Yes, how can I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: We can't predict if or how there will be an issue, so we definitely can't tell you how to fix a problem that you don't have information about.  You should always act as if everything will go horribly wrong and keep good backups.  Windows will often reassert itself as the first boot device and it can usually be fixed with `update-grub`, `boot-repair`, or BIOS settings. But again we can't tell you how to fix a problem that hasn't happened yet. Proceed with caution, document your steps, and prepare for the worst

Comment: Also if BIOS bigger issues. Windows is known to not include Linux partitions back into partition table. Data is still there and partition table can be updated if no other changes made to system. If system is UEFI, but Windows is BIOS, much better to use UEFI with gpt partitioning. But change to gpt will probably delete everything. Or have good backups.

Answer (score 0):

Last time I've tried that grub was gone. If you **reinstall** windows, the procedure will delete the grub bootloader - your image will still be present - but you can't reach it.
So after installing windows you'll need a live USB stick and reinstall grub on your device.
Since things go wrong (especially if Windows is involved) I'd save my data before doing anything. [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/831216/how-can-i-reinstall-grub-to-the-efi-partition) is a good guide on how to install grub with an USB live image