# Laptop boots directly to windows 10 in Ubuntu (tried several things, see below) on Asus laptop

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, uefi

I already tried disabling fast boot, secure boot, hibernation, fast startup. Please don't suggest me other questions suggesting this. Thank you.

**Brief Description:**

After installing Ubuntu 20.04.1 on a separate partition, with Windows 10 installed on another one, I restart the pc after installation and it just boots to Windows 10.

**Setup:**

- EFI/GPT (not mbr/bios).
- Windows 10 / Ubuntu 20.04.1 dual boot (I tried 18 but with similar results).
- Laptop: VivoBook ASUS X571GT_F571GT (it has an Nvidia gpu, but I don't reach grub anyway to encounter the issues there common with Nvidia drivers (or lack thereof)).
- Let me know if there's any missing info to add here.

**Attempts:**

- Disabled fast boot, secure boot, hibernation, fast startup
- Gave top priority to Ubuntu boot loader in EFI/bios menu
- Tried [this](https://itsfoss.com/no-grub-windows-linux/)
- reinstalled grub in EFI mode following [this tutorial](https://askubuntu.com/a/1069886/1143073)
- Resetting Windows 10 EFI entry following [this tutorial](http://woshub.com/how-to-repair-uefi-bootloader-in-windows-8/)
- Reinstalling Ubuntu several times, formatting its partition and reinstalling again
- using efibootmgr to remove Ubuntu's entry and also deleting the Ubuntu folder in EFI partition for a clean reinstallation
- Tried Linux Mint and Ubuntu 18.04.5.
- Updated EFI/bios firmware to latest version
- Tried installing boot-repair on live usb, but it gave me no option for repair (recommended repair option)

Right now, I think the current state is that the Ubuntu installer has no effect, but I could be wrong of course.

**More details/history:**
This is a new laptop. The first time I installed Ubuntu I actually had a different result which is similar to [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-fix-minimal-bash-like-line-editing-is-supported-grub-error-in-linux/), and also I got an error when I checked the box to install third party updates, so it wasn't a clean installation, keep in mind I formatted this partition multiple times after the first installation. After booting to Ubuntu from grub terminal and then restarting, I couldn't find grub anymore and it boots to windows. When I reinstalled Ubuntu again (or reinstalled grub from live usb don't remember which exactly), instead of getting the minimal grub terminal, it just freezes at Asus logo screen before grub. So it doesn't freeze at grub (due to gpu issues) but before that at the Asus logo, I had to repeat that because the gpu issue is the most common one.
And after a few other installations and attempts, it just boots directly to Windows 10, and I think the Ubuntu installation right now doesn't even work or have any effect.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-in-windows-10-ubuntu-dual-boot)

Comment: @karel Please read my answer again. I disabled hibernation and fast boot, and I also reinstalled grub from live usb.

Comment: Have a look how you installed Ubuntu. At boot-time one can select the live usb in 2 modes, an UEFI-mode and a normal usb-device-mode. If you have selected the second one, then your system won't boot via the grub and will always boot into win10

Comment: @BernardDecock On my machine I think the only way is in UEFI. When I checked the BIOS/UEFI menu at startup there was no setting to boot into legacy mode, there's really only one way to boot the USB. Also when I created the live usb, I used Rufus and configured the partition scheme and target system to be GPT and UEFI (non csm) respectively.

Comment: If you start Ubuntu on the live-usb. Open Gparted. How are different looking like?

Comment: @BernardDecock I wiped the ssd and installed Ubuntu as the standalone system, can't reproduce the same issues again.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but it could be useful to others in my own situation.
I wiped my SSD (so removed Windows 10) and installed Ubuntu on its own. This implies that Windows 10 (or the efi partition containing windows boot manager) was the cause of my problem (not being able to boot to Ubuntu after installing it) and not the hardware (my laptop).

I could try to install Windows 10 along with the current Ubuntu installation later. I have read in multiple websites that it's easier to install Windows 10 after Ubuntu as opposed to the reverse. So you could try that I guess.

Best of luck!