# Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS on HPE Microserver Gen10plus does not boot after update

Tags: boot, server, grub2, 20.04, uefi

I installed and configured Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS on a HPE Microserver Gen10 Plus last weekend. After completing the installer, it booted without issues. Some days ago I ran the available updates it prompted for. This morning it asked a reboot (*** System restart required ***) in the login message. I rebooted but it does not start anymore.

Storage config is:

```
2 4TB disks in software raid1
/ lvm on raid
/boot on raid /dev/md0
/boot/efi on /dev/sda1 and /dev/sdb2
```

I tried to reinstall grub on either disks by mounting /, /boot and /boot/efi, chroot-ing into /mnt and then install-grub (following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/831216/how-can-i-reinstall-grub-to-the-efi-partition) instruction), but with no avail. No bootable disk is found.

In /var/log/dpkg.log I found the unattended (and unsolicited!) installation of a kernel this morning.

Main question: is there a way to get the server to boot again without reinstalling the OS and losing my configuration? Any help very much appreciated!

The updates of a few days ago:

```
2021-11-29 09:22:07 upgrade libpam0g:amd64 1.3.1-5ubuntu4.2 1.3.1-5ubuntu4.3
2021-11-29 09:22:08 upgrade libpam-modules-bin:amd64 1.3.1-5ubuntu4.2 1.3.1-5ubuntu4.3
2021-11-29 09:22:10 upgrade libpam-modules:amd64 1.3.1-5ubuntu4.2 1.3.1-5ubuntu4.3
2021-11-29 09:22:12 upgrade rsync:amd64 3.1.3-8 3.1.3-8ubuntu0.1
2021-11-29 09:22:16 upgrade libprocps8:amd64 2:3.3.16-1ubuntu2.2 2:3.3.16-1ubuntu2.3
2021-11-29 09:22:18 upgrade procps:amd64 2:3.3.16-1ubuntu2.2 2:3.3.16-1ubuntu2.3
2021-11-29 09:22:19 upgrade libdrm-common:all 2.4.105-3~20.04.1 2.4.105-3~20.04.2
2021-11-29 09:22:19 upgrade libdrm2:amd64 2.4.105-3~20.04.1 2.4.105-3~20.04.2
2021-11-29 09:22:20 upgrade libssl1.1:amd64 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.8 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.9
2021-11-29 09:22:25 upgrade udev:amd64 245.4-4ubuntu3.11 245.4-4ubuntu3.13
2021-11-29 09:22:26 upgrade libudev1:amd64 245.4-4ubuntu3.11 245.4-4ubuntu3.13
2021-11-29 09:22:27 upgrade open-vm-tools:amd64 2:11.0.5-4 2:11.3.0-2ubuntu0~ubuntu20.04.2
2021-11-29 09:22:29 upgrade libpam-runtime:all 1.3.1-5ubuntu4.2 1.3.1-5ubuntu4.3
2021-11-29 09:22:31 upgrade libnetplan0:amd64 0.102-0ubuntu1~20.04.2 0.103-0ubuntu5~20.04.3
2021-11-29 09:22:32 upgrade netplan.io:amd64 0.102-0ubuntu1~20.04.2 0.103-0ubuntu5~20.04.3
2021-11-29 09:22:33 upgrade openssl:amd64 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.8 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.9
2021-11-29 09:22:34 upgrade python-apt-common:all 2.0.0ubuntu0.20.04.5 2.0.0ubuntu0.20.04.6
2021-11-29 09:22:34 upgrade python3-apt:amd64 2.0.0ubuntu0.20.04.5 2.0.0ubuntu0.20.04.6
2021-11-29 09:22:36 upgrade ubuntu-advantage-tools:amd64 27.2.2~20.04.1 27.4.1~20.04.1
2021-11-29 09:22:37 upgrade python3-update-manager:all 1:20.04.10.7 1:20.04.10.9
2021-11-29 09:22:38 upgrade update-manager-core:all 1:20.04.10.7 1:20.04.10.9
2021-11-29 09:22:39 upgrade ufw:all 0.36-6 0.36-6ubuntu1
2021-11-29 09:22:40 upgrade wget:amd64 1.20.3-1ubuntu1 1.20.3-1ubuntu2
2021-11-29 09:22:41 upgrade libasound2:amd64 1.2.2-2.1ubuntu2.4 1.2.2-2.1ubuntu2.5
2021-11-29 09:22:41 upgrade libasound2-data:all 1.2.2-2.1ubuntu2.4 1.2.2-2.1ubuntu2.5
2021-11-29 09:22:42 upgrade alsa-ucm-conf:all 1.2.2-1ubuntu0.9 1.2.2-1ubuntu0.11
2021-11-29 09:22:44 upgrade libudisks2-0:amd64 2.8.4-1ubuntu1 2.8.4-1ubuntu2
2021-11-29 09:22:44 upgrade linux-base:all 4.5ubuntu3.6 4.5ubuntu3.7
2021-11-29 09:22:45 upgrade software-properties-common:all 0.98.9.5 0.99.9.8
2021-11-29 09:22:46 upgrade python3-software-properties:all 0.98.9.5 0.99.9.8
2021-11-29 09:22:47 upgrade snapd:amd64 2.49.2+20.04 2.51.1+20.04ubuntu2
2021-11-29 09:22:53 upgrade udisks2:amd64 2.8.4-1ubuntu1 2.8.4-1ubuntu2
2021-11-29 09:22:54 upgrade cloud-init:all 21.2-3-g899bfaa9-0ubuntu2~20.04.1 21.4-0ubuntu1~20.04.1
2021-11-29 09:23:01 upgrade cloud-initramfs-copymods:all 0.45ubuntu1 0.45ubuntu2
2021-11-29 09:23:01 upgrade cloud-initramfs-dyn-netconf:all 0.45ubuntu1 0.45ubuntu2
2021-11-29 09:23:02 upgrade overlayroot:all 0.45ubuntu1 0.45ubuntu2
```

This morning unsolicited kernel upgrade:

```
2021-12-01 06:31:31 upgrade linux-generic:amd64 5.4.0.90.94 5.4.0.91.95
2021-12-01 06:31:32 upgrade linux-image-generic:amd64 5.4.0.90.94 5.4.0.91.95
2021-12-01 06:32:18 upgrade linux-headers-generic:amd64 5.4.0.90.94 5.4.0.91.95
```

Edit: I tried reinstalling the grub-efi package in chroot. This seemed to be missing. After that I installed grub on the first disk. Now I see "ubuntu" in the UEFI boot order list on the server, but it does not boot.

Comment: Hey Gottfried! It is not required to mention "SOLVED" in the title of the question. Also, instead of editing your question and including the solution in it, I request you to post an answer and accept it later. Please read this: https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Why the repeated emphasis on "unsolicited kernel upgrade"? That's completely normal behavior. If you don't want that to happen, you need to modify your system settings away from defaults.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Re the unattended updates: I have been working with Ubuntu server 16 and 18 before and I've never experienced automatic updates. I was surprised and prefer to run updates only when I'm near the box. Found the setting and disabled it.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I disabled the on-board software raid controller (which is functional in Windows only if I understand the HPE docs right) and enabled the AHCI SATA instead. Both hard disks appear in the list of bootable devices and the box boots fine! I can't figure out what I did wrong but I must have messed up some settings.