grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of `'
I dived into update-grub which launches grub-mkconfig which calls grub-probe, which is giving this error
I had a 2 disk BTRFS raid1 on my root partition when the boot disk (with the EFI and grub) failed. I am on Ubuntu Jammy 22.04
On rebooting the other disk wouldn't boot obviously because it didn't have the EFI partition and bootloader installed.
Partition Table of the Disk:
Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048          499711   243.0 MiB   EF00  EFI system partition
   2          499712       117229567   55.7 GiB    8300  Linux filesystem
   3       117229568       500118158   182.6 GiB   8300  Linux filesystem

Booted using an Ubuntu 24.04 Live USB and mounted the partition degraded. Then ran
grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi /dev/sda
grub-install: error: failed to get canonical path of `'`

Have extensively searched all online forums and well ChatGPT :) but the canonical path its looking for looks weird

I am using the 24.04 Live CD. My installation is 22.04. I have fixed the small typo I made.

The following describes something similar to what you are requesting: -  https://www.shellhacks.com/reinstall-grub-from-live-usb-uefi-lvm/

Exactly the steps I followed. But I don't get a No Errors Reported. I get the error I have put and its pretty cryptic

Did you create a new UEFI partition and initialize it on your remaining disk so grub-install can find it and install a new boot? Without this grub-install might well think its a BIOS configured system.

Similar to first link but ASK https://askubuntu.com/questions/831216/how-can-i-reinstall-grub-to-the-efi-partition

I did create a new EFI partition, formatted it as FAT32 and mounted it on /boot/efi

Pretty much the same steps, followed to the letter

Don't you mean 'sudo mount /dev/sdXX /mnt/boot/efi'?

At one time I converted my MBR to GPT and then attempted to install 24.04 over the X-MBR version of 22.04 but it failed. I tried to create a UEFI partition (like you) and repeat but it still failed. I then re-installed 22.04 (old installer) which created the new UEFI partition followed by 24.04 over that which worked. This was only way I could created a working UEFI. I have read of someone installing WIN8 (link above?) to achieve a similar outcome.

Could you provide more information? What is the background to booting 24.04 and trying to reinstall grub?

I was able to resolve this and wanted to put it out there in case it helps anyone who is looking for this particular issue.
Turns out converting the btrfs to single (from raid1) and removing the missing device solved the problem for me. Maybe the missing device was being detected with an empty name by grub-probe.
Run
btrfs balance start -f -sconvert=single -mconvert=single -dconvert=single <mount>
btrfs device remove <drive> <mount>

Refer to this article on stack exchange on removing device from raid1 on btrfs
