Need to Purge packages from/mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p5
I cannot enter my system since upgrading from Ubuntu 22.04 to 24.04. I have booted from Boot repair and tried to repair Grub. The message is "Boot repair Cannot Purge Grub2 (purge Grub* packages from /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p5). I tried to repeat the failed Boot repair lines to see if there was further information on the failure using the line
"sudo chroot mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p5 apt-get purge and got the following:
"depkg error processing package shim-signed (--configure):
Dependency problems -leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure
Errors were encountered while processing:
grub-efi-amd4-signed
Shim-signed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
I do not know how to fix this or where to go next. I did manage to mount GParted ,this shows the partitions intact with data. Any help appreciated

The following answer reports how to reinstall grub (EFI) from Ubuntu installation medium.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/831216/how-can-i-reinstall-grub-to-the-efi-partition.
