How to fix Grub this weird dual boot setup?
I can not get Grub to show up or add Ubuntu 24.04 to the Windows 10 boot manager after fresh installs of both:
Today, I freshly installed Windows 10 on my desktop computer (after having messed up my old dual boot setup), using approximately 50% of my 500 GB SSD drive.
After this was done, I freshly installed Ubuntu 24.04 on the other approximately 50% of that SSD drive, and the installation routine recognized my setup and let me choose "install next to another OS".
Now, when I boot, I either get the Windows boot manager, which only offers me to boot Windows, or I boot directly into Ubuntu, depending on my BIOS boot setup.
After having tried countless resources on the web to no avail, I gathered some data:
In my BIOS setup, I can choose between the boot modes:

UEFI or
LEGACY+UEFI (this one is selected)

In the BIOS boot options, I can choose between:

UEFI Hard Disk:Windows Boot Manager TA1: Crucial_CT525MX300SSD1), or
Hard Disk:Crucial_CT525MX300SSD1
and several others (but no "Ubuntu" or "Grub" entry available)

When I select the Windows Boot Manager, my computer boots into the Windows Boot Manager, where I can only select "Windows", which works fine.
When I select the other option "Hard Disk:Crucial_CT525MX300SSD1", then I directly boot into Ubuntu, without any boot manager.
Yet, I have several hard drives, that were all in use before when my dual boot setup was working fine (but with Ubuntu 22.04 - it was the upgrade to 24.04 that started the mess I ended up with today).
So when I look in the file manager, I see these drives (german OS, sorry for the partially german drive names):

Ubuntu 255.6 GB, ext4, mounted under '/' (contains /bin/, /boot/...)
Datenträger (= "Volume") 2.1 GB, ext4, /dev/sda2, mounted under '/media/roman/' (contains grub, vmlinuz...)
Datenträger 261 GB, /dev/sda5, mounted under '/media/roman/' (contains /users, /Windows - this must be the Windows system partition)
Volume 1.8 TB, /dev/sdb1, mounted under '/media/roman/' (contains Windows data files)
Datenträger (= "Volume") 2.2 TB, /ev/sdb2, mounted under '/media/roman/' (contains some old Ubuntu files, but was probably encrypted, it contains e.g. roman/Access-Your-Private.desktop, which can not be opened, and a few empty folders I used to have)
E_SSD 2 TB, /dev/sdc2, mounted under '/media/roman/' (contains also Windows data files)

All I understand is that obviously grub ended up on the wrong partition - at least this is what it looks like to me.
The output of the command sudo fdisk -l yields (sorry, german only):
Festplatte /dev/loop0: 4 KiB, 4096 Bytes, 8 Sektoren
Einheiten: Sektoren von 1 * 512 = 512 Bytes
Sektorgröße (logisch/physikalisch): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes
E/A-Größe (minimal/optimal): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes


Festplatte /dev/loop1: 74,27 MiB, 77881344 Bytes, 152112 Sektoren
Einheiten: Sektoren von 1 * 512 = 512 Bytes
Sektorgröße (logisch/physikalisch): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes
E/A-Größe (minimal/optimal): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes


Festplatte /dev/loop2: 269,77 MiB, 282873856 Bytes, 552488 Sektoren
Einheiten: Sektoren von 1 * 512 = 512 Bytes
Sektorgröße (logisch/physikalisch): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes
E/A-Größe (minimal/optimal): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes


Festplatte /dev/loop3: 505,09 MiB, 529625088 Bytes, 1034424 Sektoren
Einheiten: Sektoren von 1 * 512 = 512 Bytes
Sektorgröße (logisch/physikalisch): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes
E/A-Größe (minimal/optimal): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes


Festplatte /dev/loop4: 91,69 MiB, 96141312 Bytes, 187776 Sektoren
Einheiten: Sektoren von 1 * 512 = 512 Bytes
Sektorgröße (logisch/physikalisch): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes
E/A-Größe (minimal/optimal): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes


Festplatte /dev/loop5: 10,72 MiB, 11239424 Bytes, 21952 Sektoren
Einheiten: Sektoren von 1 * 512 = 512 Bytes
Sektorgröße (logisch/physikalisch): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes
E/A-Größe (minimal/optimal): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes


Festplatte /dev/loop6: 500 KiB, 512000 Bytes, 1000 Sektoren
Einheiten: Sektoren von 1 * 512 = 512 Bytes
Sektorgröße (logisch/physikalisch): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes
E/A-Größe (minimal/optimal): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes


Festplatte /dev/loop7: 38,83 MiB, 40714240 Bytes, 79520 Sektoren
Einheiten: Sektoren von 1 * 512 = 512 Bytes
Sektorgröße (logisch/physikalisch): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes
E/A-Größe (minimal/optimal): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes


Festplatte /dev/sda: 489,05 GiB, 525112713216 Bytes, 1025610768 Sektoren
Festplattenmodell: Crucial_CT525MX3
Einheiten: Sektoren von 1 * 512 = 512 Bytes
Sektorgröße (logisch/physikalisch): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes
E/A-Größe (minimal/optimal): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes
Festplattenbezeichnungstyp: gpt
Festplattenbezeichner: 2B81319B-7259-40D2-840F-8CECE208CADA

Gerät         Anfang       Ende  Sektoren  Größe Typ
/dev/sda1       2048       4095      2048     1M BIOS boot
/dev/sda2       4096    4198399   4194304     2G Linux-Dateisystem
/dev/sda3    4198400    4403199    204800   100M EFI-System
/dev/sda4    4403200    4435967     32768    16M Microsoft reserviert
/dev/sda5    4435968  515044841 510608874 243,5G Microsoft Basisdaten
/dev/sda6  515045376  516196351   1150976   562M Windows-Wiederherstellungsumgebung
/dev/sda7  516196352 1025607679 509411328 242,9G Linux-Dateisystem


Festplatte /dev/sdb: 3,64 TiB, 4000787030016 Bytes, 7814037168 Sektoren
Festplattenmodell: WDC WD40EZRZ-00G
Einheiten: Sektoren von 1 * 512 = 512 Bytes
Sektorgröße (logisch/physikalisch): 512 Bytes / 4096 Bytes
E/A-Größe (minimal/optimal): 4096 Bytes / 4096 Bytes
Festplattenbezeichnungstyp: gpt
Festplattenbezeichner: CCD52EFB-DB8E-404C-AEBB-2A46E9C5FCE3

Gerät          Anfang       Ende   Sektoren Größe Typ
/dev/sdb1        2048 3517898751 3517896704  1,6T Microsoft Basisdaten
/dev/sdb2  3517898752 7814035455 4296136704    2T Linux-Dateisystem


Festplatte /dev/sdc: 1,82 TiB, 2000398934016 Bytes, 3907029168 Sektoren
Festplattenmodell: TS2TSSD225S     
Einheiten: Sektoren von 1 * 512 = 512 Bytes
Sektorgröße (logisch/physikalisch): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes
E/A-Größe (minimal/optimal): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes
Festplattenbezeichnungstyp: gpt
Festplattenbezeichner: 9B0AB42A-5CA6-40E1-BEDA-F9CCB88D50D0

Gerät      Anfang       Ende   Sektoren Größe Typ
/dev/sdc1      34      32767      32734   16M Microsoft reserviert
/dev/sdc2   32768 3907026943 3906994176  1,8T Microsoft Basisdaten


Festplatte /dev/loop8: 10,54 MiB, 11051008 Bytes, 21584 Sektoren
Einheiten: Sektoren von 1 * 512 = 512 Bytes
Sektorgröße (logisch/physikalisch): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes
E/A-Größe (minimal/optimal): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes

Setting up hard drives and partitions has always been my nightmare (as this example shows) and I really did not find any resource on the web that would help me further here - running sudo update-grub or sudo update-grub2 and trying to boot into Ubuntu from out of Windows did not change anything.
Could someone explain to me what - if at all - I could do to enable the Grub boot manager or get Ubuntu as an option into the Windows boot manager?
Any hint would be much appreciated.

Your Windows is installed in UEFI mode, while your Ubuntu is installed in legacy mode, that's th culprit. Reinstall Ubuntu in UEFI mode, I'd recommend to disable legacy mode in the bios settings so you can't accidentally use wrong boot mode.

You should just be able to re-install grub from the install media. Following the following answer at this location https://askubuntu.com/questions/831216/how-can-i-reinstall-grub-to-the-efi-partition with one change - you will need to change the install-grub to the following: - 'grub-install --target=x86_64-efi  /dev/sdX' (use 'i386-efi' flag if necessary and select your target disk.)

The issue is that I installed Windows in UEFI mode while I then installed Linux in LEGACY+UEFI mode.
Re-installing Linux in UEFI mode solved the issue, as @mook765 stated (thank you).

Please click the large check symbol beside your answer to mark it as accepted.

@karel: Will do for sure, but I have to wait for 8 hours before I am allowed to do so.
