# How to mount my old system HDD?

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive

I recently changed from a 3.5 to 2.5 inch HDD on my computer and also went from ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04. Now when I try to mount the old HDD I get the following:

```
  sudo mount /dev/sda /mnt/oldhome
      mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda,
      missing codepage or helper program, or other error

   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail or so.
```

When I do that I get the following log output:

```
[ 1474.327826] EXT4-fs (sda2): unable to read superblock
[ 1474.327924] EXT4-fs (sda2): unable to read superblock
[ 1474.328007] EXT4-fs (sda2): unable to read superblock
[ 1892.657070] EXT4-fs (sda): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
```

fdisk -l gives me the following output:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00005dd2

Device     Boot  Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *      2048     499711     497664   243M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       501758 1953523711 1953021954 931.3G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       501760 1953523711 1953021952 931.3G 8e Linux LVM

Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

I hope that you can help me with this tiny, but annyoing problem!

Comment: Also this if encrypted. You need to install lvm2 & cryptsetup. http://askubuntu.com/questions/719409/how-to-reinstall-grub-from-a-liveusb-if-the-partition-is-encrypted-and-there-i?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to mount the partition, not the block device (hard disk).

For example;

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/oldhome/
```

You will not be able to mount /dev/sda2 because that is the extended partition (which means that other partitions, starting from /dev/sda5, reside within it).

To mount /dev/sda5, you might have to use LVM commands, not sure. (I'm not an expert with LVM, so hopefully someone else will help you out with /dev/sda5). You will probably need to mount `/dev/md-x` to somewhere (with 'x' being a number such as `/dev/dm-127`.

I had a very quick search on the internet and here is the first link I found.

https://sathyasays.com/2008/10/01/how-tomounting-lvm-partitions-from-a-command-prompt-or-a-root-shell/

Comment: Thanks, the lvm link helped a ton, I was familiar with normal partitions, but not with lvm!