# Pulled Hard Drive Out of Dead Linux Computer. Root Was Encrypted. I Know the Password

Tags: system-installation, mount, hard-drive, encryption

I pulled hard drives out of two dead computers. They were old Linux installations of mine and the root folder was encrypted. I've got them attached to my newest Ubu computer as external drives.

I cannot figure out how to cd / to the external drive (variations on cd /dev/sdb/ all fail) and then apply the password to the root folder.

There is probably something rock simple I'm missing here, and any enlightenment would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to make sure you have the drivers and then use LVM commands to mount and unencrypt partition(s). See https://askubuntu.com/questions/719409/how-to-reinstall-grub-from-a-liveusb-if-the-partition-is-encrypted-and-there-i

Comment: Assuming the old drives are LUKS-encrypted, does anything here help -->
 [Mount encrypted volumes from command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63594/mount-encrypted-volumes-from-command-line)