# Grub menu error Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: grub2, menu

Good morning, I started my computer this morning to find the Grub_ menu prompt error I assume.

I tried the boot-repair option with no luck. I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS only no dual boot and my main drive is encrypted with Ubuntu. I'm not sure what caused this as it was working fine yesterday. I will post some information to hopefully help with any questions. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Output of boot-repair link below

https://pastebin.com/DhLw0Y1L

Comment: Are you getting grub menu or grub> or grub rescue> ?

Comment: Are you getting grub menu or grub> or grub rescue> ? Have you tried enter, typing exit & enter or a chroot type boot? Do not know LVM, so commands would be different for UEFI, LVM & encrypted partition. See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/53578/can-i-install-in-uefi-mode-with-the-alternate-installer/57380#57380

Comment: It’s the GNU Grub menu. I’ve tried exit and enter

Comment: If you get grub menu, have you tried recovery mode? It then gives options to command line or boot. You may then need to mount LVM and run fsck on it.

Comment: So I cannot access recovery mode. I followed the instructions from here https://www.linux.com/learn/how-rescue-non-booting-grub-2-linux%20%20 

The results aren't showing any of the files.

ls gives me (hd0,gpt3) (hd0,gpt2) (hd0,gpt1) (hd1)
ls (hd0,gpt3) shows unknown filesystem
ls (hd0,gpt2) show lost&found /efi /boot /grub mem.test abi. initrd. system.map vmlinuz.*
ls (hd0,gpt1) shows efi/ boot/
ls (hd0,1) shows efi/ boot/

So I'm not finding any files to finish the steps.

Comment: Also when I installed Ubuntu I did a full disk encryption. I am able to boot from my live cd and trying to fix it from here. I read a few questions where the disk encryption was alittle different. If that helps any.

Comment: Full disk encryption is a lot different, plus it uses LVM, volumes for system & swap, not partitions. https://askubuntu.com/questions/719409/how-to-reinstall-grub-from-a-liveusb-if-the-partition-is-encrypted-and-there-i

Comment: Yes I have found that link and been trying to get it to work. I'm stuck with two issues. I'm guessing I didn't mount /sys and a bad resolving address to get grub.
root@ubuntu:/# sudo grub-install /dev/sda
Installing for i386-pc platform.
device node not found
root@ubuntu:/# apt-get install --reinstall grub-efi-amd64
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]

Comment: Not not know LVM. But grub-pc is BIOS and grub-efi-amd64 is UEFI. You only need one or other depending on whether your install is BIOS or UEFI.

Comment: I'm fairly certain its UEFI. When I follow the instructions on the link you posted I get a 404 not found for the grub install. When I follow the instructions on https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2266650 I get to installing grub and it says DEVICE NODE NOT FOUND. Thanks so much for your help btw.

Comment: Ok just starting at the beginning if you could walk me through. I am stuck at  /dev/[VOLUME GROUP NAME]/[LOGICAL VOLUME NAME] /mnt
root@ubuntu:~# /dev/ubuntu-vg/root /mnt not working
Found volume group "ubuntu-vg" using metadata type lvm2
root@ubuntu:~# lvscan
  ACTIVE            '/dev/ubuntu-vg/root' [<221.40 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/ubuntu-vg/swap_1' [980.00 MiB] inherit

Comment: Do not know LVM. You might try Boot-Repair, but before doing anything with it, be sure to mount LVM & un-encrypt your install. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair