# Reinstall Windows 10 on a dual-boot system with encrypted Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, windows-10

So 8 months ago I got a new laptop with Windows 10 and I spent a couple of days setting up an encrypted Ubuntu 18.04 system on it. Now Windows 10 doesn't boot and I need to reinstall it. I am afraid that reinstalling will erase the `GRUB` bootloader and mess up my encrypted (LVM under LUKS) system set up through `/etc/fstab` and `/etc/cryptstab`. How to avoid these problems?
Here's my setup:

```
sda                     8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk  
├─sda1                  8:1    0    16M  0 part  
├─sda2                  8:2    0 736.2G  0 part  /media/win
└─sda3                  8:3    0 195.3G  0 part  
  └─lxfiles           253:3    0 195.3G  0 crypt 
    └─vgfiles-lvfiles 253:4    0 195.3G  0 lvm   /media/data
nvme0n1               259:0    0   477G  0 disk  
├─nvme0n1p1           259:1    0   260M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2           259:2    0    16M  0 part  
├─nvme0n1p3           259:3    0 237.9G  0 part  
├─nvme0n1p4           259:4    0  1000M  0 part  
├─nvme0n1p5           259:5    0   500M  0 part  /boot
├─nvme0n1p6           259:6    0   3.8G  0 part  
│ └─swap              253:2    0   3.8G  0 crypt [SWAP]
└─nvme0n1p7           259:7    0 233.6G  0 part  
  └─rootfs            253:0    0 233.6G  0 crypt 
    └─vgroot-lvroot   253:1    0 233.6G  0 lvm   /
```

Basically I want to re-install Windows on `nvme0n1p3` and its EFI bootloader but avoid it touching anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first, if you ain't sure about what you are doing, make sure that your important data is backed up.

Second, installing windows after ubuntu will overwrite GRUB with windows boot loader. I don't think that there is a way to avoid it.

So, I found two ways to deal with that:

#### 1- Set the windows entry inactive

Like [Kana mentioned here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/242219/355168), is possible to set the Windows boot manager entry to inactive, as Windows overwrites the entry to 0000 and changes the boot order.

As [Karlovsky120 also reminded](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/547371/355168) it may only work if Ubuntu has been installed in UEFI mode. You can check it using the command: `if test -d /sys/firmware/efi;then echo efi;else echo bios;fi`.

#### 2 - Reinstall GRUB after the windows installation

There are many ways to repair GRUB, as recommended on the [official ubuntu help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Fixing_a_Broken_System)
Specifically about encrypted volumes, there are many other posts about it:

- [How to reinstall grub from a liveUSB if the / partition is encrypted and there is a separate /boot partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/719409/how-to-reinstall-grub-from-a-liveusb-if-the-partition-is-encrypted-and-there-i)
- [Unable to reinstall GRUB on encrypted filesystem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/260469/unable-to-reinstall-grub-on-encrypted-filesystem)
- [Samuel Colvin - gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/samuelcolvin/43c5ed2807e7db004b1058d0c9bfb068)

Comment: Thanks, I did the first option of setting the Windows bootloader as inactive and got GRUB back! all in all, a relatively painless experience reinstalling Windows on a dual-boot system.