# GRUB and boot-repair An error occurred during the repair. Data missing

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi, boot-repair

I have a laptop with four drives. One drive (encrypted) for Ubuntu, one for windows, and 2 for storage. I recently installed windows after having my Ubuntu setup and working. After the windows 10 install I was unable to boot ubuntu normally. On boot I would see the grub minimal BASH like line editing. Being unfamiliar with it I turned to boot-repair. I had to use a live ubuntu install disc to get boot-repair to even work. I was getting warnings about my encrypted drive not mounting and boot-repair being unable to verify the content. I proceed anyway. Here is the output

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Crx9SYpYP4/

There are many unsolved post on this issue. My main concern at this point is recovering the data on the drive. If it's not possible I'll have to do a fresh install, but that will mean I lose data that I can't recover. Please help!

Another strange thing is that when I check my BIOS I see Ubuntu showing up on 3 different drives now. I can't explain it or fix it.

[image]

Comment: First rule with encryption is to have really good backups. Issues often cause breakage & then only recourse is restore from backup. You show two ESP on NVMe drive. Most UEFI only allow one ESP per drive. Both show Ubuntu boot files, so one must not be correct. See GUID/partUUID of ESP: Windows is using p2 to boot from UEFI menu. Ubuntu is using p1. Line 507 shows grub trying to boot from ESP, not your install. You have to mount & decrypt install before running Boot-Repair, so it can see rest of install. Can you backup encrypted data using live installer, first?

Comment: @oldfred when I did live boot with ubuntu I mounted and decrypted the drive. I was able to navigate it through file explorer, but boot-repair still couldn't see it. I after running boot-repair it logged me back into Ubuntu, but everything is gone now. I don't know if it was deleted or it's just not pointing in the right direction to load the data.

Comment: I do not know encrypted installs. Did you backup when you were able to mount the encrypted partitions? Did you remove one ESP? I would copy files/folders from one to other & back then up, but then still have to reinstall grub & Windows boot loader to have correct settings.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/719409/how-to-reinstall-grub-from-a-liveusb-if-the-partition-is-encrypted-and-there-i-

Comment: @oldfred When I look in the BIOS I see ubuntu showing up on 3 different drives... which makes no sense at all. I only installed it on one. I added a picture to my original post. Please let me know if you have any other ideas. I'm all out of them.

Comment: UEFI remembers entries. So did you or do you have install on other drives? Your report has so much info on encrypted & issues, it is hard to see drives, GUIDs, UUIDs and normal boot path. Rerun report with decrypted install, but I still do not know encrypted installs, just grub.

Comment: There is no point in encrypting system files. The idea of encryption is to protect **data files** that contain sensitive information from prying eyes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best (of fastest was) way is to do a fresh install of Ubuntu (always install Windows before installing Ubuntu).
Of course you want not lose any data.  So you have to boot Ubuntu first from the installation medium, en select 'Try Ubuntu without installing'. Then  go to the terminal  and mount the file-system  "mount - o rw,remount / ". So you can enter in Ubuntu and do what you have to do. (backup).  If necessary do something research of booting the file system with the installation medium.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I learned my lesson this time. Windows doesn't play well with Ubuntu, unfortunately I still need to use it for some software that just doesn't run as well on Ubuntu. Long term I plan to retire windows altogether. Next time I'm installing windows then Ubuntu.

Comment: Sometimes you can use  some windows software with wine in Ubuntu. (wine is in the repository).   But i understand your problem.  Once i was retired i banned windows completely of my machine.