# Deleted initrd.img and vmlinuz

Tags: kernel, encryption, initrd

Running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and I accidentally deleted initrd.img of ONE kernel and vmlinuz of the OTHER kernel. I can not boot the OS up, not even in recovery mode. How do I restore either initrd.img or vmlinuz of either kernels so I can boot up? I have a USB with a working Ubuntu live OS, it boots up fine.
The harddrive is encrypted with LUKS too btw. All help greatly appreciated, I need to recover it ASAP for work. Thank you all.

Comment: You should be able to chroot into system & reinstall kernel & grub. Often easier with Boot-Repair, but since encrypted, you have to mount LVM & decrypt it before running any updates, so /, esp, & /boot can be seen. In advanced options choose reinstall grub & new kernel. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair   &           
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/  & https://askubuntu.com/questions/63594/mount-encrypted-volumes-from-command-line  chroot: https://askubuntu.com/questions/719409/how-to-reinstall-grub-from-a-liveusb-if-the-partition-is-encrypted-and-there-i-

Comment: Please tell me how to mount LVM and decrypt it?

Comment: See links in first comment.