# Is there a way to recover data from a drive that was an LVM partition?

Tags: ssd, data-recovery, lvm

I'm a bit new to ubuntu, apologies upfront for gaps in my understanding.

One of our device broke down recently and needed to be RMA.

The device had 2 drives, an internal 30gb drive and a 1 tb ssd. The device had been setup to combine it as 1 drive (which I would guess is from LVM? We have another device that's the same model and it has the same setup).

I have the ssd, but the internal memory was taken with the RMA'd device.

I tried inserting it into a different device (no LVM) and it's appearing as unallocated.

Is there a way for me to recover the data within that ssd?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it also encrypted? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/339011/how-do-i-mount-an-lvm-partition/339621#339621  Similar but extra commands for encryption. https://askubuntu.com/questions/719409/how-to-reinstall-grub-from-a-liveusb-if-the-partition-is-encrypted-and-there-i?rq=1

Comment: @Levente Not sure yet. It's dependent on the extend of the damage on the device. If the device is not reparable, they may just send us a new one instead.

Comment: @oldfred I don't think so. I have the root password for the device it was originally from though, if that changes anything.

Comment: Can you not install lvm2 and mount volumes per link?

Comment: @oldfred I have not tried, how do I do so?

Comment: See links I posted above. Did you not look at them?

Comment: @oldfred sorry, I tried it but I'm having issues with the output. I'm not sure if its correct, but I didn't have a volume group, so I made one using vgcreate vg1 /dev/nvme0n1. So I finally received output on the steps. However, I'm getting "0 logical volumes activated" in volume group vg1 at the activate lvm step. Not sure if this is also any indicator, but I noticed that the nvme has no disklabel or disk identifier when using fdisk -l

Comment: I do not use nor really know LVM. But if you did not have a volume group, you must not have had LVM? It sounds like that is erased? or damaged? In Disks (gnome-disks) and upper right hand icon is Smart Status. It can run tests on drives, but all I know is whether it says drive is good or bad.

Comment: @oldfred i think there's a bit of a mixup. I took the drive from a roscube that needed repairs. Other roscubes that I have access to appear to have their drives setup to appear as one giant drive, hence why I believe the ssd I'm trying to recover data from was also set as LVM. My device that I'm using doesn't use LVM, so I didn't have volume group before this. Apologies if that wasn't clear.

Comment: No idea how Roscube may configure drives. If RAID, or something else.