# Ubuntu could not resolve symbol, give a AE_NOT_FOUND message and boot procedure gets stuck

Tags: boot, encryption, acpi

I am on Ubuntu 22 and did a SW update on July 13th, 2023. The previous update was done on Aug 5th, 2023. After this latest update, I get the following messages:

```
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [_SB.PCI0.GPP0.SWUS], AE_NOT_FOUND (20221020/dswload2-162)

ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20221020/psoject-220)

ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [_SB.PCI0.GPP0.SWUS.SWDS], AE_NOT_FOUND (20221020/dswload2-162)

ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20221020/psoject-220)

blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)
```

(last message repeated 6 times)

Everything was running properly up until this last update.

I did a search on Stack Overflow, there are some posts on similar messages but not exactly this one. The other articles say these are annoying bugs, can be ignored and the boot procedure continues. However in my case, the boot procedure gets completely stuck and there seems to be no way to make it proceed.

One more thing: my disk is encrypted, the first step is to give the encryption password.

Anyone having this issue and an idea what can be done?

I just wanted to log into my Ubuntu desktop and ran into this issue.

Comment: So you still get the request to decrypt your files? Then you are past the grub boot stage and into something else, often video related. Can you boot to grub menu and boot recovery mode. If only one install, you have to press escape between UEFI/BIOS screen and where grub menu would normally appear. Recovery mode will give some repair options. Do you have good backps? If using encryption very good backups are required as somethings only choice is reinstall & restore from backup. What video card/chip?

Comment: Actually I don't get prompted for the decryption password. As far as I can see, the latest update obviously introduced some new variable which seems to be undefined.

Comment: do you get grub menu and then boot recovery mode? What video card/chip? What brand/model system? If no backup that is the first thing to do. https://askubuntu.com/questions/63594/mount-encrypted-volumes-from-command-line Reinstall grub, and when chrooted you can also backup or other repairs: http://askubuntu.com/questions/719409/how-to-reinstall-grub-from-a-liveusb-if-the-partition-is-encrypted-and-there-i-

Comment: Hi, I have been out for a couple of days, here I am back. My machine is a HP OMEN, the CPU is a AMD Ryzen 5 5600G with Radeon Graphics. When starting, I get the following 3 options:

Comment: Ubuntu, Advanced Options for Ubuntu, UEFI Firmware.

Comment: After several attempts, I got the option to reboot in recovery mode. I updated grub as you indicated and could continue the boot process. I have now access to everything, first thing to do now is a complete backup. Thanks a lot for your help.